# Auto-Focus on JQuery autocomplete (Not the first one)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I realize that this question has been asked before, and the clearest solution that I've seen can be found here:

[Focus on a jQuery autocomplete result (not necessarily the first)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572817/focus-on-a-jquery-autocomplete-result-not-necessarily-the-first)

I need the first solution that you can view in the selected answer: my item must be selected client-side, and that solution looks ideal. My goal is essentially to have the focus settle on the item from the menu that is already in the input text box (which triggers the opening of the ui menu), if there is one. Not to select the item, but only to focus on it. I also cannot use the "search" functionality because that would eliminate other options around the option that is under focus.

Sadly for me, it fails on this line:
var menu = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu. Firebug tells me: TypeError: $(...).data(...) is undefined.

Here is my full open event function callback declaration as a reference.

```
            open: function (event, ui) {
                var termTitle = $(event.target).val();

                var menu = $(this).data("uiAutocomplete").menu
                    , i = 0
                    , $items = $('li', menu.element)
                    , item
                    , text
                    //, startsWith = new RegExp("^" + this.value, "i");
                    , startsWith = new RegExp("^" + termTitle, "i");

                for (; i < $items.length && !item; i++) {
                    text = $items.eq(i).text();
                    if (startsWith.test(text)) {
                        item = $items.eq(i);
                    }
                }

                if (item) {
                    menu.focus(null, item);
                }

            }
```

As you can see, it's mostly taken from the link given above. I am at a loss as to what the problem could be. If you have any idea *pleeese halp!*

Thank you very much,
Eli

UPDATE: I am using JQuery 1.8.3. Could this be related?

Comment: This code exactly works for me. Just tested in my environment. What happens if you switch `this` for the ID of the element you are initializing the autocomplete control on?

Comment: Hi Kyro. I'm afraid the same thing happens if I specify the id instead of using "this".

Comment: The version could very well be a factor. Could you set up a jsFiddle to reproduce the error?

Comment: I might set up a jsFiddle might a little later; currently at work =). I'll also test with a different version.